# Check xml attribute value is present or not with jquery

Tags: jquery

Below is part of my xml

```
<atom:entry>
    <atom:id>Alex Kane</atom:id>
    <atom:title type="text/html">Alex Kane</atom:title>        
    <wplc:field id="gender">MALE</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="doc_source">default</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="degree">M.D.</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="defaultcontext">/poc</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="contentsourcetype">Seedlist</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="contentSourceType">Seedlist</wplc:field>       
    <wplc:field id="docid">Alex Kane</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="title">Alex Kane</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="language">English</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="doctortype">Plastic Surgery</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="condition">3D Surface Motion Capture</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="condition">3D Surface Scan</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="condition">Kinematic Motion Capture</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="condition">Cleft Lip</wplc:field>
    <wplc:field id="condition">Cleft Palate</wplc:field>      
</atom:entry>
```

In this I need to check whether id="condition" is there or not? whether id attribute contains the value condition or not? like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type :"GET",
    dataType: "xml",
    url : "childrens_new.xml",
    success : function(data){

        var countCondition=0;

            $(data).find('atom\\:entry, entry').each(function(){                
                 $(this).find('wplc\\:field, field').each(function(){                           

                    if($(this).attr('id') == "condition"){      // here i need to check             

                            countCondition++;
                            return false;

                    }
                });
            alert("Number of doctors with no Condition - " + countCondition);

    }
});
});
```

How can I achieve this?

- updated the question, there am looping through each parent xml tag.

Comment: How you load this xml? Inline in HTML? a var of javascript? Via AJAX? Please, add more info

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works but you have a typo error, you need to close the first each function

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
type :"GET",
dataType: "xml",
url : "childrens_new.xml",
success : function(data){

    var countCondition=0;

        $(data).find('atom\\:entry, entry').each(function(){                
             $(this).find('wplc\\:field, field').each(function(){                           

                if($(this).attr('id') == "condition"){      // here i need to check             

                        countCondition++;
                        return false;

                }
            });
       }) ;
        alert("Number of doctors with no Condition - " + countCondition);

   }
}) ;
}) ;
```